# Telegram bot API. Scroll window

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Hello I want to make this feuture in Telegrem, but I cannot find It in documentation and I don't know it name. Thanks for help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use InlineQuery to do it:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py